# Piezo barely audible

Tags: arduino, current, piezo-buzzer

Let me start by saying that I'm pretty new to electronics, so be gentle ;)

I'm able to get good, solid tones from my piezo when nothing else is connected. When I connect it alongside my servo + keypad, the tones are so quiet that I can't hear it unless I get really close to it. I'm assuming that the piezo isn't receiving enough current, but I don't know if that assumption is correct, or how to fix the issue.

The piezo plays a tone on each press of the buttons on the keypad. Once the correct combination has been entered, the servo is attached, moved 90 degrees, then detached, and the LEDs change from red to green.

Here's my build:

[image: Fritzing render]

Schematic:

[image: Schematic]

Parts:

- Servo: Micro A0090 [Sparkfun product page](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9065?)
- Piezo: CEM-1203 [Datasheet](http://www.chinasound.com/Product/CET/CET12A3.5-42-2.0R.htm)

Function called for playing tones:

```
void playTone(long duration, int freq)
{
  duration *=1000;
  int period = (1.0 / freq) * 1000000;
  long elapsed_time = 0;
  while(elapsed_time < duration)
  {
    digitalWrite(pinSpeaker, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(period / 2);
    digitalWrite(pinSpeaker, LOW);
    elapsed_time += (period);
  }
}
```

Called on keypress:

```
playTone(750, 500);
```

Full code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 3;
const byte PINLENGTH = 4;
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3'},
  {'4','5','6'},
  {'7','8','9'},
  {'*','0','#'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {5, 4, 3, 2};
byte colPins[COLS] = {8, 7, 6};

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

char PIN[PINLENGTH]={'2','5','8','0'};
char attempt[PINLENGTH]={0,0,0,0};
int z=0;

Servo lock;
int pos=0;

int pinSpeaker=11;

int redLED = 12;
int grnLED = 13;
boolean armed = true;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(pinSpeaker, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(grnLED, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  resetLock();
  Serial.println("* SYSTEM ARMED *");
  Serial.println("  Ready...");
}

void resetLock()
{
  lock.attach(9);
  for(pos=20; pos>0; pos-=1)
  {
    lock.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }
  lock.detach();
}

void closeLock()
{
  lock.attach(9);
  for(pos=lock.read(); pos>=1; pos-=1)
  {
    lock.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }
  lock.detach();
}

void openLock()
{
  lock.attach(9);
  for(pos=lock.read(); pos<100; pos+=1)
  {
    lock.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }
  lock.detach();
}

void correctPIN()
{
  armed=false;
  playTone(750, 2500);
  openLock();
  Serial.println("* SYSTEM DISARMED *");
  Serial.println("  Ready...");
}

void incorrectPIN()
{
  playTone(750, 1000);
  Serial.println(" * Incorrect PIN *");
  z=0;
  Serial.println("  Ready...");
}

void checkPIN()
{
  int correct=0;
  for (int q=0; q<PINLENGTH; q++) {
    if (attempt[q]==PIN[q]) {
      correct++;
    }
  }

  if (correct==PINLENGTH) {
    correctPIN();
  } else {
    incorrectPIN();
  }

  for (int zz=0; zz<PINLENGTH; zz++)
  {
    attempt[zz]=0;
  }
}

void readKeypad()
{
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  if (key != NO_KEY)
  {
    switch(key)
    {
    case '*':
      if(armed==false){
        armed=true;
        playTone(750, 1000);
        closeLock();
        Serial.println("* SYSTEM ARMED *");
        Serial.println("  Ready...");
      }
      z=0;
      break;
    case '#':
      if(armed==true){
        Serial.print("\n");
        delay(100);
        checkPIN();
      }
      break;
    default:
      if(armed==true){
        playTone(250, 2000);
        Serial.print(key);
        attempt[z]=key;
        z++;
      }
    }
  }
}

void playTone(long duration, int freq)
{
  duration *=1000;
  int period = (1.0 / freq) * 1000000;
  long elapsed_time = 0;
  while(elapsed_time < duration)
  {
    digitalWrite(pinSpeaker, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(period / 2);
    digitalWrite(pinSpeaker, LOW);
    elapsed_time += (period);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if(armed==true)
  {
    digitalWrite(grnLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(grnLED, HIGH);
  }
  readKeypad();
}
```

How can I get proper output from the piezo?

Comment: Nice that you linked to the render. Now open Fritzing, go to the schematic tab and post a link to the schematic so that we can edit it in.

Comment: Also do you have any information about the servo or the piezo? Part numbers would be good and links to datasheets even better.

Comment: Can you post the section of the code you're using to generate tones for the piezo? The microcontroller in Arduino should be able to provide enough current for the piezo to work correctly (piezo at most uses 30 mA, while the output pin can provide as much as 40 mA before being damaged).

Comment: Are you using interrupts in the rest of your code?

Comment: No, I'm not using any interrupts (I was actually just reading about them for the first time a few minutes ago). Is this a situation where they would be useful?

Comment: They can be depending on what your code is doing, as for instance they can free up the code from polling for events in a loop to do other things. For example of you set an interrupt on change for a button pin, you don't have to waste cycles polling for the change, the interrupt will take care of "monitoring" this, then the interrupt routine deals with it as necessary. Anyway, the reason I asked here is it may have actually caused issues if you had set an interrupt incorrectly and it was stopping your main code from running smoothly.

Comment: In other comments, you keep mentioning things like "... not nearly as loud as when the piezo was the only thing connected" and "the piezo sounds great when nothing else is connected".  Which clearly means that the piezo is working fine.  You'll have to explain more about what's going on with your hardware and what specifically you are changing between when it sounds loud and when it doesn't.  It could be problems with your power supply not providing enough current, some timing interaction in the code, who knows!  We need more info.

Comment: Is the piezo hanging in free air? If so press it against your desk to use it as sound board.

Comment: @JimParis: The only thing that changed is the introduction of the servo and keypad. Wiring of the piezo is unchanged. When a key is pressed on the keypad, the digit is stored in an array, the tone is played, and the array is checked against the stored code. The servo isn't engaged until the correct sequence has been entered.

Comment: @jippie: No, it is attached to the breadboard, which is sitting on the desk

Comment: "The only thing that changed is the introduction of the servo and keypad" -- You just plugged them in, or you also changed the code?  You really need to provide us _all_ info.  Sharing the code is also crucial if you're changing the code between when it's working and when it's not working.

Comment: I've added the project's full code

Comment: Try this: Get a 6v dc power supply for the arduino, or put 4 aa batteries in series and connect positive to vin and negative to GND. Change the power connection to the servo from 5v on the arduino to VIN on the arduino. Now see if the piezo is loud.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not current, but voltage.  Piezo elements are inherently fairly high voltage devices; there are those which will work somewhat at logic levels and may even be designed for it, but they will be louder at higher voltage up to the point where they depolarize (or depending on how mounted, conceivably crack).

Some of the low voltage piezo alert devices which do not need an external oscillator because they have an internal one exploit resonance behavior to boost the voltage above the external supply.

Additionally, piezo devices will generate more output at higher audio frequencies than lower ones - they can move quickly, but not very far.

While your question says piezeo, and that is what I have answered, that may not actually help your problem.  Your link is to the data sheet for a magnetic transducer with a coil, which is a completely different sort of device.  A piezo is a crystal of a special ceramic which deforms in response to an electric field (typically it is bonded to a metal disc for a better impedance match to air at audio frequency)

Comment: Sorry about the bad link. I grabbed the wrong product number initially, and corrected the link when I discovered it. It seems you were a bit too fast for me ;) The correct link is [here](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/CEM-1203.pdf)

Comment: Also, the piezo sounds great when nothing else is connected. I'm feeding 5v via USB.

Comment: Try a higher frequency.  Also try connecting the other parts of the circuit one wire at a time and see when you loose output.

Comment: Ack! Copied the same incorrect link. I've edited the question with the correct link: http://www.chinasound.com/Product/CET/CET12A3.5-42-2.0R.htm

Comment: @Steve that might be the part you actually have, but it's not a piezo either.  Like the sparkfun part, it is a magnetic transducer.  Piezos (for audible use in air) tend to be larger in diameter, like the arduino tutorial picture.  When the noisemaking assemblies are bare they are a thin brass disc with a grey-white piezo ceramic layer on them, like this: https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/images/products/10293=02.jpg

Comment: Ah, that is definitely not the part that I have, although the Sparkfun kit identifies the transducer as a piezo. The markings on the back are "CET12A3.5", which is what led me to the updated link I provided. [Here is a picture of it](http://www.infinitelement.com/tmp/cet12a3.jpg). Looking back at the Sparkfun page, it appears that the [first link](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/CEM-1203.pdf) may have actually been correct.

Comment: To some extentent, a magnetic transducer is to an inductor what a piezeo transducer is to a capacitor - so if you measure a DC resistance of tens of ohms across it at a low test voltage, it's likely magnetic.  The geometry also suggests that - a piezeo that small would have an extremely high resonant frequency.  If you want a piezo disk to experiment with, look for the little coin cell magnetic switch alarm gizmo in a dollar store - inside you may find an unsealed reed switch, a piezo disk, an inductor, and a transistor.  But for one with specs, go to an electronics supplier.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, if you are not using interrupts (I thought possibly they were interrupting your tone routine) then it seems you are overloading your power supply.

If it is an Arduino, then if I recall correctly the little (not heatsinked) linear regulator is not good for much more than 150mA or so.
An easy way to confirm would be to measure the +5V power rail and see if it sags (scope or multimeter) when you operate the servo and buzzer (i.e. run your code as normal)
If you have a scope you can also check the output of the pin the buzzer is connected to.

There is no datasheet for the servo, but they can easily draw a few hundred mA.
Exactly how much current the servo is drawing depends on the load, it should only draw maybe 10-20mA when idle, but maybe 500mA if driving a large load. Again, the only way of finding out is to measure it.

Considering the buzzer is rated for 35mA, it's not ideal to drive it directly from the Arduino pin anyway, as it can probably only source ~20mA or so without the output voltage sagging (check datasheet for exact figures, I've never used an Arduino)
Much better would be to drive it using a transistor, or use a lower current buzzer (piezo are generally lower, although you can get very low current magnetic types)

Comment: I've added a transistor (P2N2222A), with the Base connected to pin 11 on a 10Kohm resistor, the collector bridging the piezo to 5v, and the Emitter to ground. The piezo is producing the same volume as before. I'm not certain I'm using proper connections... it's a modification of an example I found.

Comment: The transistor won't fix it if the problem is the supply voltage, you need to confirm and fix this first. Do you have a multimeter and/or scope? Can you measure the supply voltage (the +5V regulator output, not the adaptor input - you can measure it at the +5V connector header pin) with and without the servo/keypad attached? Let us know what you read.

Comment: I've never actually learned to use one (like I said, I'm just getting started). I have a 19-range analog multimeter that I picked up from RadioShack, but the user's guide sucks pretty bad... :/

Comment: In a simple test on a AA battery, I got a reading of 2.5v with the dial set to the 5v range. This is consistent with one of the bad reviews I read on this same meter. Unless we're both using it incorrectly, it looks like the meter is junk, and won't be of much help in my situation :(

Comment: Ah, okay. You really need to get hold of a decent multimeter and a basic scope if you are planning on doing this kind of thing often (it sounds like you may be) These tools give you an eye into the electronic domain, otherwise you are limited to guesswork, trial and error. The scope will quickly become your most used and valued tool.

Comment: Looks like a trip to the electronics store is in my near future :)

Answer (score 1):

What frequencies have you tried?  The buzzer you're using is designed to be driven at 2048 Hz.  Its datasheet shows a plot of the expected response versus frequency on page 2.  Note from that chart that the expected response at 200 Hz is about 25 dB lower than the response at 2 kHz -- that's a big difference!  It's hard to convert from "dB" to "perceived loudness" particularly when different frequencies are involved, but it's a logarithmic scale, so it's pretty large.  If you want to try to get into details, see [this](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-levelchange.htm) page, but much easier would be to just try 2 kHz and see how it differs.

Comment: Sorry if I sound like a total noob here... Your explanation makes total sense to me, but I'm not sure how you're calculating Hz. I bumped up the frequency in my function params to 2000, and am getting a much "louder" response from the piezo, but it's still not nearly as loud as when the piezo was the only thing connected. With the function I'm using, how can I go about calculating the max frequency range?

Comment: The piezo data sheet I could find at sparkfun is for a family of devices, and the lowest resonant frequency is 2KHz, others go up to 6.  So keep going higher.  Consider making a sketch which listens on the serial and responds to +/- keys sent from the serial monitor, printing the new count values (you probably don't need to care about actual frequency)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out how to make a Piezo loud after way too long tinkering with this issue! You can use 5V and you get a ton of noise.. The trick is to add an Auto-transformer to the circuit that you can get at the dollar store. I made an instructable on it here:

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-an-Arduino-driven-Piezo-LOUD/

If anyone can identify this dollar store part on Mouser, that would be cool. cheers, tom

specs: Pin-1/2 ~154 ohms Pin 2/3 ~ 8ohms. Not sure on the inductance although a similar project used 91mH and 2mH as shown on the instructable.